# Get RecyclerView instance onCreateViewHolder to set params

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Alright guys, I need to find a way to change the distance to the top on orientation change for the RecyclerView because it's different in Horizontal and Vertical, I got this working on the items, onBindViewHolder  but I also need to set the params for the RecyclerView, the following code doesn't work:

```
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    // Create layout params for the RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params
        = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    // Set them margins
    params.setMargins(0, spanCount * 500, 0, spanCount * 10);
    // Get reference, this doesn't work
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) parent.getChildAt(0); // Doesn't work
    rv.setLayoutParams(params); // <- Throws NPE
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}
```

I also tried casting RecyclerView to the parent and to the view, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a reference of the RecyclerView to your Adapter's constructor.

Comment: Use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams class not RecyclerView.LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the LayoutParameters of a RecyclerView, it shouldn't be in the adapter. The Fragment / Activity must handle the orientation changement and update the LayoutParam if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the layout of RecyclerView when screen orientation changed, why not just change it in [onConfigurationChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration))?